# Declared Interface errors when building the project

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, selector, declaration

I im fairly new to ios development, and following the tutorial exercise on chapter 4 of the book 'beginning ios5 development' i have run into some compile errors on my code.

here's what my header code .h file looks like

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

   @interface BIDViewController : UIViewController

   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *namefIELD;

   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberField;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sliderLabel;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *leftSwitch;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *rightSwitch;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *doSomethingButton;

   -(IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender;
   //to initialize the 'done' button when editing to confirm you have finished editing/

   -(IBAction) backgroundTap:(id)sender;
  - (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender;
  - (IBAction)switchChanged:(id)sender;
  - (IBAction)toggleControls:(id)sender;
  - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
  @end
```

and here's my .m code where im facing the error "no visible @interface for 'UISegmentedControl' declares the selector 'setOn:animated;'

```
  @synthesize leftSwitch;
  @synthesize rightSwitch;


 - (IBAction)switchChanged:(id)sender {
 UISwitch *whichSwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
 BOOL setting = whichSwitch.isOn;
 [leftSwitch setOn: setting animated: YES];  //the error lies here/
 [rightSwitch setO: setting animated: YES];  //the error lies here/
 }

 - (IBAction)toggleControls:(id)sender {
 }

 - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
 }
 @end
```

the error statement is "no visible @interface for 'UISegmentedControl' declares the selector 'setOn:animated;'

pls help, that would be highly appreciated and voted for :)

@PhilipMills ...here's what i'm talking about, as soon as i click on a leftside or rightside of the segmented control object a break point is automatically made on my delegated header code here

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 #import "BIDAppDelegate.h"

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
       @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([BIDAppDelegate         class])); //the breakpoint appears here.
       }
 }
```

Comment: When you say "leftside or rightside of the segmented control object" you sound as if there is still confusion over what kind of UI object(s) are actually being used.  I thought you'd changed to switches.

Comment: basically, following the tutorial, i dragged a segmented control from the library, but changed the type from UISegmentedControl to UISwtich when making the outlet connection

Comment: I don't know that book but you need to be consistent.  If you use segmented controls, you have to declare them that way and only call their methods.  If you want to use switch methods/logic, then you have to have UI elements that match.  It would be different if one inherited from the other, but they don't.

Comment: that's interesting because according to the book, a segmented control was dragged out from the library, but i looked into the books archive online to compare their code to ours', turns out, the code indicates UISwitches as you pointed out, quite confusing. Anyway, thanks a million for your response, far too kind. Can i trouble you to recommend a decent book for a beginner ? ..im also looking into the stanford lectures on itunes U though they can be time consuming

Comment: I don't know any that are really good for beginning iOS.  I have the Stephen G. Kochan book on Objective-C for reference and, apart from that, usually look at Apple's sample code for specifics.  They also have a good tutorial you can find by searching for "second ios app".  I hear the Stanford series is good.

Comment: thanks for that, i'll be looking into that. One more thing, :) how do you suggest i declare a UISegementedControl object and implement it in the .m file ? i mean a little code you write on here if you don't mind, if that's not a hassle

Comment: Open the documentation tab of the Organizer window.  Go to the class description for UISegmentedControl.  It lists five projects there that have sample code related to it.  Download a few of them.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UISwitch` has a `setOn:animated:` method but a `UISegmentedControl` does not.  I'll guess that you assigned objects to `leftSwitch` and `rightSwitch` that are not the kind you intended (or the tutorial intended).

Comment: i changed the UISegmentedControl to UISwitch, everything works fine until i click on the leftswtich and get a 'signal SIGABRT' error -_-

Comment: OK, so we've moved on to the next error...this is programming.  :-)  You'll need to give some details about the stack at the time of the error and perhaps the code that executes when the switch is activated.

Comment: when ever i click on the on the leftbutton of the segmented control object, the program automatically makes a break point on the header delegate code..this is what i mean. i have included this code in my original question.

Comment: That's Xcode being stupid.  By default, it doesn't stop on uncaught exceptions but just points to the beginning of the program.  Try going into the Breakpoint Navigator tab and setting a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions.

Comment: so i decided to step over and the button doesn't work at all, the program closes down, lol i having a good time with is xcode..